# jquery toggleClass over the course of 3.5ms

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Why is this function not working properly? Everything works as it should, with the exception of the toggleClass toggling over the course of 3.5ms. It toggles correctly, but no animation occurs.

This code below is a rough illustration of a more complex navigation, but the idea is the same.

```js
$('ul#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(2) a').click(function() {
      $('ul#menu-main-menu').toggleClass('nav-border', 350);
  });
```

```css
ul#menu-main-menu {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-border {
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id='menu-main-menu'>
  <li>
    <a> First</a>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a> Second</a>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a> Third</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using [css transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property.

```
transition :border-radius 350ms;
```

Full code:

```js
$('ul#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(2) a').click(function() {
      $('ul#menu-main-menu').toggleClass('nav-border', 350);
  });
```

```css
ul#menu-main-menu {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition :border-radius 350ms;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-border {
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='menu-main-menu'>
  <li>
    <a> First</a>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a> Second</a>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a> Third</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a better solution for me and it works beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, if you can use css transitions do it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jquery ui?  Only the jquery ui version of toggleClass takes a duration.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Comment: no I am not... I was not aware of that. Let me add to the snippet and see if that fixes the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I added the jQuery UI and that fixed it. Thanks Taplar

Comment: @Sergio Using Jquery UI may fix your issue. But Performance of the animation will not be up to the mark. But CSS transitions would use the GPU and give you a sleek animation.

Comment: True, however the question was about why the toggleClass was not working as he expected, :)

Comment: Thank you both. Either option works great, but the css is just a more optimal solution for me.